# Linux encryption middleware for mount

Tags: linux, encryption, mount, nfs

I have an NFS share (or it can be any mounted file system)

I do not trust other readers of the NFS server

Is there a way to add a middle layer that encrypts on writes and decrypts on reads transparently to the network share?

Example:

**Write**

I create file secret.txt
I save it to a certain folder
"Middleware" encrypts the file

**Read**

I open file secret.txt (found encrypted mount point as the middleware presents unencrypted file names)
"Middleware" decrypts the file
I can read the content as if it was on a regular FS.
Encrypted file gets written to NFS

Comment: Do you have root access? What is your research effort? [This page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs) reads "if you want to set up eCryptfs directly on top of an NFS mount, with no local copy of the files, eCryptfs may crash or behave incorrectly. If in doubt, EncFS may be a better choice in this case". I have no experience with EncFS but maybe this will point you towards a solution.

Comment: I think EncFS had some security issues, but don't quote me on that.